# Error installing Wine on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, wine

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and tried everything to install Wine on it but all that I get is this error

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me, I need to use Photoshop CS6 on Linux.

Comment: See the description on the ppa: https://launchpad.net/~wine/+archive/ubuntu/wine-builds

Comment: The repository that you are attempting to use, "http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu" hasn't been updated since 2017 and therefore does not even know about focal release (20.04). Get rid of that repository and install from Ubuntu software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 2):

Your output suggest that you are doing it the hard way. Here is an easier way:

1. [Delete that PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).
2. Since you just changed your apt sources, run `sudo apt update`
3. Install the 20.04-compatible Wine from the Ubuntu Repositories: `sudo apt install wine`

Do not skip any steps. Stop if you encounter errors.

Open a new question for any errors or problems that you encounter (or use the Search box a the top of every AskUbuntu page).